# dynamic rendering in _document.tsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to add a message to the IE browser in my application built on react and next js that it is not supported.
The code adds in pages/_document.tsx

```
export default class MyDocument extends Document {

    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
                <Head>
                    <script
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                            __html: `
              (function () {
                const ua = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.navigator.userAgent;
                const msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
                const trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
                let isIe = false;
   
                if (msie > 0 || trident > 0) {
                   isIe = true;
                   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
                    document.getElementById("isIeBox").innerHTML = isIe;
                  });
                }
                console.log("ie", isIe) // this work
            })();
                  `,
                        }}></script>
                   

                </Head>
                <body>
                    <p id="isIeBox" style={{ display: "none" }}></p>
                    <IE />
                   

                    <Main /> 
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}
```

In script I added code that render information about  IE browser. The problem is that I would like to dynamically render depending on the value of **isIe** and display `<IE />` component  or `<Main /> <NextScript />`. However, after disabling `<Main /> <NextScript />` I will get a bug:
*Server Error
TypeError: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.*

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: You shouldn't disable `Main` or `NextScript`. Try moving the logic to `_app` instead.